# OpenLayers PROJ4JS projection of OSM layer is slightly translated?

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, openstreetmap, wms, proj

I am new to OpenLayers and haven't been able to figure out this problem by searching online. I am using a custom projection in OpenLayers 7.4.0 with proj4 2.9.0 as demonstrated in [this example](https://openlayers.org/doc/faq.html#how-do-i-change-the-projection-of-my-map-). The projection definition I am using was taken directly from [EPSG:28992 Amersfoort / RD New](https://epsg.io/28992-8572). Here is my code:

```
import proj4 from 'proj4';
import { register } from 'ol/proj/proj4.js';
import { get as getProjection } from 'ol/proj.js';

proj4.defs("EPSG:28992",
  "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889"
  + " +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel"
  + " +towgs84=565.4171,50.3319,465.5524,1.9342,-1.6677,9.1019,4.0725"
  + " +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"
);

register(proj4);
const rd = getProjection('EPSG:28992');

const map = new Map({
  interactions: defaultInteractions({ dragPan: false }).extend([
    new DragPan({
      condition: function (mapBrowserEvent) {
        return (
          mapBrowserEvent.originalEvent.isPrimary &&
          mapBrowserEvent.originalEvent.button < 2
        );
      },
    }),
  ]),
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM({
        projection: rd
      })
    }),
    new ImageLayer({
      source: new ImageWMS({
        url: 'https://service.pdok.nl/rws/ahn/wms/v1_0',
        params: { 'LAYERS': 'dtm_05m' },
        projection: rd
      }),
    }),
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [150000, 463000],
    zoom: 13,
    projection: rd
  })
});
```

I've added an OSM layer and a WMS layer ([taken from here](https://service.pdok.nl/rws/ahn/wms/v1_0?SERVICE=WMS&request=GetCapabilities)). But when I look at my map, the OSM and WMS layers are slightly translated (only translated, not scaled or skewed):

[image]

Is there something wrong in the projection definition? Or is it something with the OpenLayers OSM TileLayer? What am I missing here?

Comment: There is a difference between that projection definition and the one used by the server.  You could try any of these alternatives
 https://epsg.io/28992-4833
 https://epsg.io/28992-15934
 https://epsg.io/28992-1112
 https://epsg.io/28992-1672
 https://epsg.io/28992-8572
 and this very old GeoServer definition https://geoserver-users.narkive.com/GbCNUXVz/rd-rijksdriehoeksmeting-coordinate-system-epsg-28992 seems to work well with your data.  OSM is always served as EPSG:3857 and will be reprojected by OpenLayers, specifying a projection in its options has no effect.

Comment: @Mike, I've tried all of those, including the old GeoServer definition and none of them do the job. I had indeed already figured out that the projection attribute in those layers did not do anything. When I import both those OSM and WMS layers in QGIS with the CRS set as EPSG:28992 they do overlap (using some kind of inverse projection EPSG:19914). I don't get it...

Comment: If you specify EPSG:3857 as the WMS projection OpenLayers will reproject it as well as The OSM - Inefficient but the alignment looks better

Comment: Hi @Mike, thanks for the help. I want to stick with EPSG:28992 so I compromised and used another source (WMTS) for the background map, which does align correctly. I took it from here: https://service.pdok.nl/brt/achtergrondkaart/wmts/v2_0?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMTS

Comment: This appears to be the proj4 definition used by the service https://pdok-ngr.readthedocs.io/handleidingen.html#in-de-browser-proj4js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-image-custom-proj-forked-n3mjcs?file=/main.js

Comment: The definitive definition is the EPSG registry (epsg.org) ~ https://epsg.org/crs_28992/Amersfoort-RD-New.html

Comment: @nmtoken using the correct definition will not help if the service provider is not also using it.  Then it can get very awkward if one provider is using the correct definition and another is not and you need both sources on the same map.